# Allow System Account to start impersonated process

Tags: c#, process, system, impersonation

I am working on a project where I have a Windows service running under `Local System Account`.

What I want to do is to start another process (C++ application) that should write files to disk.

If I just use `Process.Start`, then the target application also runs under `Local System Account`, and as far as I know I can not simply write files anywhere.

For this reason I'm trying to make the target application run as a different user.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Path\to\Application.exe", parameters);
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.UserName = "Username";
System.Security.SecureString sec = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (Char c Password)
    sec.AppendChar(c);
psi.Password = sec;
psi.Domain = ".";
psi.LoadUserProfile = true;
Process.Start(psi);
```

But I am getting a Win32 Exception telling me the "Acces is denied". 
Does anybody know how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Have you checked the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16805952/806549) question?

Answer (score 0):

Check the file system permissions. Does the user you are using have execute permissions for the specified application?

Comment: Yes, it does. I#m trying to use the systems local administrator account

Comment: Hm. I've tested it and it works fine for me... Where do you get the exception. Have you tried executing something else like cmd.exe?